# Rendering template object in an if comparison string

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I've been trying to do this and getting no results

```
<ul>
    {% for topic in topics %}
        <li {% if request.get_full_path == "/topic/{{ topic.topic_slug }}/" %}class="is-active"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{% url "TopicView" topic.topic_slug %}">{{ topic.topic_name }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

The error, I'm guessing is from the {{ topic.topic_slug }} being rendered in the string. I'd like it to be "/topic/tech/" during rendering but that seems not to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use `{{ }}` inside a `{% %}` so you need to do this in a different way. There are many possibilities.

Try using

```
 {% if request.get_full_path == "/topic/"+topic.topic_slug+"/" %}
```

but the way I would do it is to simply use your class to do the work of returning the path. `/topic/tech/` looks like what people usually return from a `get_absolute_url` class function:

```
 class Topic:

     ...

     def get_absolute_url(self):
         return '/topic/{}/'.format(self.topic_slug)
```

and then in your template, simply use:

```
 {% if request.get_full_path == topic.get_absolute_url %}
```

(Note that if you already have an absolute_url, simply use another function name. e.g. `get_my_topic_slug_url()`).